# HTML Position Fixed error

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Making a website for my university project and have hit a small problem when viewing my site in Chrome (which is usually great for compatibility so I'm probably playing dumb). I've set the header bar and 'controls_container' as both position:fixed in order to have them in view when scrolling down the page, yet in Chrome these aren't fixed, whereas in IE, Safari and Firefox it works as intended.

This is the top of the page viewed in Chrome:
[image: webpage in chrome]
This is after scrolling down in Chrome:
[image: scrolled in chrome]
(Header bar scrolls up, as does the breadcrumb buttons on the left) 
This is after scrolling in IE:
[image: scroll in IE]

Can't remove z-index from the video as it's my background video.
Here is the link to my site, any help would be much appreciated! 
http://conet.co.uk/p_c_h/explore.html

Comment: if you want the header to be fixed , then what exactly is the script section which handles window.scroll part do?

Comment: Looks like more of a weird rendering issue. The DOM explorer shows that the elements are where they should be.

Comment: @Sai That hides the navigation bar when you reach the bottom of the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elements you’ve mentioned — header bar and `.controls_container` — are actually fixed. The problem here is in rendering, which acts odd, when you use background video.

Try to add `backface-visibility: hidden;` or `transform: translateZ(0);` to the styles of fixed elements and the problem go away. These attributes put your fixed elements in separate rendering layer — stacking context — and browser renders them correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a rendering issue in Chrome. If you delete the "banner_video" node, everything works as expected.

See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=402211